# C++ variadic function templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

The concept of variadic templates is quite confusing to me and I want to make it a bit more complex (well I think...).
Let us consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class base  
{  
    template <typename... E>  
    virtual void variadic_method_here(E... args) = 0;  
};
```

and an implementing class:

```
class derive : public base<some_object> 
{  
    void variadic_method_here(concrete_args_here);  
};
```

How do I do that?

Comment: As far as I know, templates can't be virtual, variadic or not.

Comment: @pmr - wasn't aware that I can do that. I almost never read faq's and getting started guides. Thnx =)

Comment: @RoyiFreifeld That might as well explain why you try to do something the language does prohibit. :)

Comment: @pmr - Nah... That's just lack of knowledge, or the need to use this "dark side" of C++.

Answer (score 4):

I think if I were faced with this problem I'd use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and overloads to solve the problem.

e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Impl>
class base {
public:
   template <typename... E>
   void foo(E... args) {
      Impl::foo_real(args...);
   }
};

class derived : public base<derived> {
public:
   static void foo_real(double, double) {
     std::cout << "Two doubles" << std::endl;
   }

   static void foo_real(char) {
     std::cout << "Char" << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {
  derived bar;
  bar.foo(1.0,1.0);
  bar.foo('h');
}
```

Comment: Which still leaves the problem of runtime-polymorphism OP is apparently aiming for.

Comment: @pmr - They don't specifically ask for runtime polymorphism - to me it seemed like they wanted compile time polymorphism but didn't know about CRTP

Comment: You could be right. The `virtual` in OPs code could be a not-so-concious decision.

Comment: @awoodland - You're right. I never heard about CRTP and it sounds like a good idea, but I'm still not sure it will solve my problem.
The derived class might be decided by some clicks on GUI of my application.
Will it work if I have 2 or more derived classes?

Comment: @RoyiFreifeld - sounds like you want runtime polymorphism then if there's more than 1 derived class in use in your application. The problem with `template virtual` functions is how does the compiler decide which types to instantiate for? There's no reason to assume that where the compiler sees the call and where it's implemented are in the same translation unit, so figuring out which variants to instantiate in derived classes is (in general) impossible for the compiler.

Comment: @awoodland - let me try explaining it a little bit better: I have a single base pointer. The construction will happen on runtime, but there's still only one. Like a Strategy/State design pattern if you like. That's why I used the virtual keyword.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a templated virtual function.